# How to Deploy OSGI bundle of smooks in servicemix?

Tags: smooks

When i create simple maven project and run inside eclipse for smooks then it works fine but when i create osgi bundle for that and deploy it in servicemix then it shows following error...

I put my smook configuration file in servicemix_home/ConfigurationFiles/smook/......

Ex : org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to apply processing unit [org.milyn.javabean.ext.PropertyChecker] to [org:milyn:smooks:unknowndoc:/smooks-resource-list/jb:bean/jb:wiring].
org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to apply processing unit [org.milyn.javabean.ext.PropertyChecker] to [org:milyn:smooks:unknowndoc:/smooks-resource-list/jb:bean/jb:wiring].
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.processVisitorException(SmooksDOMFilter.java:823)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.access$700(SmooksDOMFilter.java:134)
       ...
Caused by: org.milyn.cdr.SmooksConfigurationException: Bean class 'com.test.pojo.Order' not avilable on classpath.
        at org.milyn.javabean.ext.PropertyChecker.getBeanClass(PropertyChecker.java:97)
        at org.milyn.javabean.ext.PropertyChecker.getBeanType(PropertyChecker.java:78)
        at org.milyn.javabean.ext.PropertyChecker.visitBefore(PropertyChecker.java:47)

Answer (score 0):

Change Classloader
Get current class loader from `getClass().getClassLoader()` and set in

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
```

and

```
smooks.setClassLoader(classLoader);
```